# About a error of Google Cloud Platform: The requested 54.0 CPUs exceeds the allowed maximum of 20.0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to test TPU performance following this article: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tpu-resnet/#0

But at the train job commit step, Cloud Shell display the error below:

```
 ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.jobs.submit.training) RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota failure for project my-proj-495852. The requested 54.0 CPUs exceeds the allowed maximum of 20.0. To read more about Cloud ML Engine quota, see https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/quotas.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.QuotaFailure
  violations:
  - description: The requested 54.0 CPUs exceeds the allowed maximum of 20.0.
    subject: my-proj-495852
```

I applied to increase the quota below from 20 to 60.

Compute Engine API Autoscalers

but Google only set it to 50.

I applied to increase the quota below from 8 to 60,

Compute Engine API CPUs

and this time Google said "Unfortunately, we are unable to grant your quota increase at this time. "

Can anyone tell me which quota config item should I increase? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error refers to [Cloud ML Engine quota documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/quotas). In there, you can find that the AI Platform CPUs quotas [do not count against the Compute Engine CPUs quota](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/quotas#cpu-quota).

This documentation mentions that there are certain quotas that can be requested by the Console, but I do not found AI Platform CPUs quota; so, you can request AI Platform CPUs for your training job (default 20) through this [form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1f-tmYYl8uiV6KcWFLsNKwWnTvk4KwQYsCzZHcb3g2YM/viewform) and the process is [explained in this link](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/quotas#requesting_a_quota_increase).

Last but not least, for [Free Tier quota increase requests won't be granted](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial), it is necessary to upgrade. I'm not quite sure if this is your case if you have already upgraded you can go ahead to request more quota.

Hope this help.